# Error TS2339- Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, development-environment

I have a React+Typescript project working fine a day ago ! When I tried to run it today suddenly 100's of erros of same type are occuring.

The type of error is as follows:

```
class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
              x:true;
              y:true;
        };
     }
    toggleone = () => {
         this.setState({ x: !this.state.x })
    }
}
```

Previously these errors were not there and with no modifications they are occurred. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

`React.Component` is a generic interface with two type arguments, both with defaults: the props the component receives and the state the component maintains. State defaults to `{}` (no state items at all), but your component has two state members, `x` and `y`. So you'd need to do

```typescript
class Home extends React.Component<{}, {x: boolean; y: boolean;}> {
    // ...
}
```

or as its own interface

```typescript
interface HomeState {
    x: boolean;
    y: boolean;
}
class Home extends React.Component<{}, HomeState> {
    // ...
}
```

As for why this suddenly started happening: The code you've shown has no TypeScript type declarations or similar in it at all, suggesting it was originally JavaScript code and you added TypeScript later.

---

Side note: You'll also need to declare the type of `props` in the `constructor`:

```typescript
constructor(props: {}) {
    // ...
}
```

...and fix the typos in the state initializer (the `;` after `true` should be `,`). (There's also no `render` method, but I'm assuming you just left it out to keep things minimal in the question.)